# Include optional text versions within one file

Tags: conditionals, comments

I'm still new to `LaTeX` and I'm not sure if this can be done, so here goes:

I've got two `.tex` files, there pretty similar and instead of updating them individually, which as got to be a pain. I want to merge them as one. In that single file is there a way of including certain text elements (without having to comment everything out)

Here's a simplified version:

```
Gwen Stefani
%She's so dreamy
%I hate her
```

You don't want to uncomment everything - and have conflicting text, but an easy way to have two versions within the same file - but can create a pdf depending on which version I'm after:

```
Gwen Stefani
%She's so dreamy {version A text}
%I hate her {version B text}
```

Which prints as version A or version B

```
Gwen Stefani
She's so dreamy
```

or

```
Gwen Stefani
I hate her
```

Comment: In my point of view this is not 'optional' but conditional

Answer (score 1):

A very rudimentary version since there is no clue provided how the 'versions' are organized.

Use a `\newif\ifversionA` switch and set it to true with `\versionAtrue` or false with `\versionAfalse`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newif\ifversionA 
\versionAtrue


\begin{document}
Person X 
\ifversionA

-- is so dreamy
\else

-- is not really lovely
\fi


\versionAfalse
Person Y
\ifversionA

-- is so dreamy
\else

-- is not really lovely
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before any complains occur again: Of course, a wrapper macro would be better for this ;-)